# How can I remove a file using Java?

Tags: java

How can I remove the file with Java? I tried using `java.io` as below, but it didn't work. I tried another approach, but it didn't work either.

```
package com.mkyong.file;
import java.io.File;

public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\Users\Felix\Desktop\cmploop.png");

            if (file.delete()) {
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but it don't work"? Do you get some errors, exceptions?

Comment: you didn't escape the backslashes, so the string is parsed into `C:UsersFelixDesktopcmploop.png`. try `C:\\Users\etc...`

Comment: you code it doesn't compile

Comment: Please [don't use the `File` class anymore](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). It's outdated and uninformative. Use the `Files` class instead.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I do not agree with this, while it may be old, it is not deprecated and is still _very_ widely used. [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: @MattClark The fact that it's being used merely means that one needs to know about it. But new code should not be written using it. Have you read the article I linked to? The `File` class does not give you enough information as it doesn't throw exceptions when methods fail. Thus, you're stuck with "why didn't it work?".

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have never had an issue with _File_, and think that the exceptions that it throws are sufficient enough to debug my code. I have been Googling since you posted that, and have yet to find a single other article saying that _Files_ should be used. Even all example code on Oracle's JavaDoc pages use _File_. _Files_ is also a non serializable object, whereas _File_ is.

Comment: @MattClark What exceptions does it throw for `delete` and `renameTo`? And have you ran into [this part of the Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Felix\\Desktop\\cmploop.png");
```

Maybe the problem it's that it is avoiding your backslashes.

**Why you have to put a backlash before a backlash?**

Well, in Java, if you want to use special characters inside a `String`, and that they will be a part of the `String`, you have to put a `backlash` before of them. Here a example:

```
String prove = "Hello \\hello\""; 
System.out.println(prove);

String prove = "Hello \\hello""; 
System.out.println(prove2);
```

**Output:**

In the first one you will see --> `Hello \hello"` in your console.

In the second one it will give you an error because it recognise the second `double quote (")` as the end of the `String`.

If you want some additional info you can see it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to escape the backshlashes for the parsing, try to use a double backslash after C: →

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\Felix\Desktop\cmploop.png");
                               ^
```

Comment: I think you mean File("C:\\Users\\Felix\\Desktop\\cmploop.png"); as Error404 points out. The code you posted doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

in java, backslash (`\`) cannot be writen alone and has to have another character after it.

> A character preceded by a backslash () is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler.

if you put \n it will react as ENTER key (will go 1 line down) 
if you put \t it will react as a TAB (will put a TAB space)

you can see the whole list here :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

now, if you want to write `\` alone it will make an error, so as writing `"`will end the `String`.

to solve it, you you can just put another `\` before it.
if you want to write `\` you will have to put another `\` before, it will look like that `\\`. 
if you want to write `"` you will have to put `\` before, it will look like that `\"`.

that will turn the `\` and the `"` into a "normal" character and the compiler will not use then with their usual way.

so, to write 
`"C:\Users\Felix\Desktop\cmploop.png"` 
you need to turn in into
    `"C:\\Users\\Felix\\Desktop\\cmploop.png"`

Answer (score 1):

Other than the fact that you're not escaping the backslashes, you should stop using `File` as it has some odd behavior depending on the OS you're running. `Files` is more robust:

```
Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("C:/Users/Felix/Desktop/cmploop.png"));
```

And yes, you can use normal slashes too.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it as a linux path. You don't care on witch OS the application run.

```
 File file = new File("/Users/Felix/Desktop/cmploop.png");
```

The response of Error404 is correct too i think.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Felix\\Desktop\\cmploop.png");
```

Comment: Still not work guys :( `import java.io.File;

public class apples{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Version:B5");
        try {
         File file = new File("/Users/Felix/Desktop/cmploop.png");

            if (file.delete()) {
             System.out.println(file.getName() + "System:File Has Been Delete");
            } else{
                System.out.println("System:Opps Something Worng!");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}`

Comment: If you get the Exception i think it's because you try to get the fileName of a file that doesn't exist anymore.
If you want a more specific response you will have to gave us the stacktrace and reopen your topic wich as been closed.